# Unable to set value via protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

In my Objective C code I had this:

```
if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
    id<UITextInputTraits> field = view;
    field.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert that to swift, so I did this:

```swift
if var field = view as? UITextInputTraits {
   field.enabledReturnKeyAutomatically = true
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error saying that 'field' is immutable.  What's the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by Swift's peculiar way of dealing with optional protocol requirements. Optional protocol properties have no setter. (I regard this as a bug in the language.) You'll have to work around it.

You can say (horrible):

```
switch view {
case let field as UITextField:
    field.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
case let field as UITextView:
    field.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
default: break
}
```

Another way (equally horrible):

```
let setter = #selector(setter:UITextInputTraits.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically)
if view.responds(to:setter) {
    view.perform(setter, with: 1 as NSNumber)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue though.  The view might be a UITextField, or it might be a UITextView.  That's why I'm trying to use the protocol that they both implement, instead of the concrete class.

Comment: I know. It sucks. I've revised my answer to cover both cases but it still sucks. File a bug report!

Comment: I've added a second equally horrible solution. What a mess.

Comment: File a bug report, and reference my 19730251 which was filed in February 2015. There is no Swift setter for a protocol's optional properties.